# Why is not the direct multiplication applicable to count the total number of ways to choose digits

Tags: combinations

> A common problem that says to make $8$-digit phone numbers, assuming that the first digit can’t be a $0$ or a $3$? Re-solve the previous problem, except now assume also that the phone number is not allowed to start with $433$.

$\\$I have solved both of the problems and especially the second one after a wrong trial. I am trying to find out why the first trial was wrong.

Here is what I did to solve the second problems in first trial.

If the number is not starting with $4$ then there are $9$ ways to choose digits other than $4$ and same argument for not selecting $3$'s and for the rest part there are $10$ ways to select any digit from $0-9$.The total number of way, becomes $9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 10^5=\ 72900000$, which is wrong. I would like to understand why this approach is not correct or why a direct multiplication cannot be applied to solve this problem. I hate to ask such elementary question but I want to understand the reason to fail to solve the problem at first attempt. Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: You arguably *could* use a direct multiplication approach., but it would be that rather than picking the first second and third digits separately we pick the first three digits simultaneously.  There are $1000-1$ valid ways to pick the first three digits simultaneously giving $999\times 10^5$.  Do not confuse the statement "Not allowed to start with 433" with the statement "The first digit is not allowed to be a $4$ regardless any other chosen digits while the second digit is not allowed to be a $3$ regardless any other chosen digits, etc..."  43712345 is a valid phone number.

Comment: Your argument counts the number of ways to avoid $4$ as the first digit *and* $3$ as the second digit *and* $3$ as the third digit.  But it won't count acceptable phone numbers, such as those that begin with $333$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution you're assuming that the first digit isn't 4, the second digit isn't 3, *and* the third digit isn't 3. That and should be an or.

In particular, your answer is not counting the number $43000000$.

Answer (score 2):

The *correct* answer should exclude only those numbers where the first digit was $4$ **AND** the second digit was $3$ **AND** the third digit was $3$.

*Your* answer excludes all numbers where the first digit was $4$ **OR** the second digit was $3$ **OR** the third digit was $3$.

Comment: I see almost everyone suggesting to use $OR$ but would you please clarify the reason for not using $AND$ in the calculation? This is the area where I get confused to choose an 'OR' or an 'and'.

Comment: For example, you excluded the numbers such as $41123456$ (because of leading $4$), numbers such as $73956721$ (because of second $3$) and $55399011$ (because of the third $3$) - none of them beginning with $433$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are including the other invalid phone number possibilities which start with $0$ and $3$. The best approach would be to find the number of valid phone numbers not starting with $0$ and $3$ and then subtract possibilities with $433$.

Possibilities where number does not start with $0$ or $3$ $=8\times 10^7$

Possibilities where number does not start with $433$ $=10^5$

Total Possibilities $=80,000,000-100,000=79,900,000$